# What is incorrect in this sql query?

Tags: sql-server, join, updates

```
update v, s
set v.closed = 'Y' 
where v.closed <> 'y' 
  and v.canceldate < '12.01.2017'  
  and s.salesrep1 = 'bd' 
  and v.orderno = s.orderno
```

This is my query and I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: which db you are really using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you mixed up what rdbms product you use. The error message is from MS SQL Server, while the question is (well, was) tagged as mysql.

The syntax used in the question is allowed in mysql, but is not allowed in MS Sql Server, hence the error message.

In MS Sql Server try the following syntax:

```
update v set v.closed = 'Y' 
from v inner join s 
on v.orderno = s.orderno
    where v.closed <> 'y' 
        and v.canceldate < '12.01.2017'  
        and s.salesrep1 = 'bd'
```

See ms sql server reference on [update statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for details

Comment: I'll add that, assuming v.canceldate is one of the date-related datatypes, the best choice of literal format is the unseparated form of YYYYMMDD (e.g., '20171201'). See [Tibor's guide](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I would pur it like this (on sql server)

```
update v
set v.closed = 'Y' 
From v inner join s 
On v.orderno = s.orderno
    Where v.closed <> 'y' 
    and v.canceldate < '12.01.2017'  
    and s.salesrep1 = 'bd'
```